# Can create and delete files through samba, but not modify?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm connecting from Windows 7 to Ubuntu Server 10.04 using samba. I can create new files in the share, delete those files, but if I try to edit a file, and then save it, I get an access denied. My User in Windows is the same as the one I'm connecting as and as setup in Ubuntu. This is very odd. I also have trouble copying files to Ubuntu as well. It errors but lets me copy them anyway.

Comment: Can you post your smb.conf?

Answer (score 3):

Creating and deleting files is controlled by permissions on the directory.  Modifying the file is controlled by permissions on the file.  You may have a mask which is removing the write privilege from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add/modify/delete files in Linux?  If not, then your problem is with Linux file permissions.  Once you can do everything at the Linux level, then try Samba.  If you still cannot edit the file, then it's a Samba permissions.  Check out the file and directory masks.  Are you specifying valid users/groups?

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the directory and file permission using

```
chmod -R 775 /path/to/folder
```

I've done this with selected directories in my file server and it worked.

Note that there are consequences in making files/folders "world-writable"

You can also create groups per shared folder and chown each folder per group